# Swift3 Project does not compile when others pull from git repo

Tags: xcode, git, swift3

My project compiles successfully on my computer but when I push the project to the remote others pull it, they get build failed error.

Compiler says error is because of a third party framework. Compiler does not understand a protocol that exists in fact. I think it is because of pods but I'm not sure.

I compared the project that I have with the one comes from remote repo with FileMerge but there is no difference.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

Select the file that is not compiling , open the right panel and on the File Inspector check the target that your file belongs.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, yes, I cleaned the project :(

Comment: In the Clean Project menu if you press 'alt' it shows the option of Clean Build Folder. Have you try this ?

Comment: Yes I did that too.